# Adding attributes with jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm trying to add an attribute to an element. Basically, I want the jquery code to change it from this:

```
<p class = "slider-price">X</a>
```

To this:

```
<p class = "slider-price" data-position = "[point-of-center-position(x)], [point-of-center-position(y)]">X</p>
```

Here's the demo of what I tried adding above the `</body>` tag:

```
<script>var attrbt = '"' + ((($(this.parent()).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(this.parent()).scrollTop() + "px") + ', ' + ((($(this.parent()).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(this.parent()).scrollLeft() + "px") + '"';
$("p.slider-price").attr('data-position', attrbt);</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhu68qk9/

What I'm trying to say though it's that normally I should add the attribute 'data-position = "100, 100" ' by myself (I'm using FractionSlider, so this would position the element inside the slider). However I want the element to be centered, so I thought using jquery to get the position would help.

Comment: And where do those values come from; don't just show us your failing/broken code, explain what it should do. (And certainly don't just hide that broken code on JS Fiddle, post it here; we're happy to help, but making it harder for us to help doesn't help yourself at all.)

Comment: Well i want the attribute to have two values that would indicate the position of an element if placed on the center of the screen, like data-position = "100, 100". Sorry if I'm explaining poorly, I'm a beginner!

Comment: I tried to write the code based on this one: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/GbDw9/ , however i want it to **add** an attribute to **<p>**, not to center it.

Comment: what is `this`? Show code in the question

Comment: Those 2 lines are the entire code I tried to make. There's no cutting out from the script code. The code isn't entirely copied from somewhere, it's just an attempt of mine which I know it's bad. However I added my attempt so you could understand better what I want to do.

Comment: So you want the coordinates of the point of the centre of the screen?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean!

Comment: What I'm trying to say though it's that normally I should add the attribute 'data-position = "100, 100" ' by myself (I'm using FractionSlider, so this would position the element inside the slider). However I want the element to be centered, so I thought using jquery to get the position would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues on your snippet.

1. You are not loading jQuery library so you cannot select a DOM element(such as p.slider-price) like $("p.slider-price"). To fix that, you should load the jQuery library (in fiddle you do that by choosing it from the frameworks & extensions menu).
   Than, using jQuery you will be able to change the attributes, for example:

`$("p.slider-price").attr('data-position', "2");`

2. You have some issues on trying to calculate the attrbt (mainly because you should first understand what this and parent means).
   In your case, you are assuming that parent is the parent DOM element of your p element, but javascript or jQuery doesn't understand that.
   So, first you select(and/or save) your p element, than you would be able to get its parent and than you could calculate different values.

Combining all what I explained, you will get this fiddle which does what you are expecting:
http://jsfiddle.net/p62qyvax/4/

Answer (score 1):

`$(this.parent())` throws an error: this.parent is not a function. You should use `$(this).parent()` as jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

How about breaking out your code into some helpers.

```
var ypos = function(el) {
   var $el = $(el)
   var h = ($el.parent().height() - $el.outerHeight())/2;
   var offset = $el.parent().scrollTop();
   return h + offset;
}
var xpos = function(el) {
   var $el = $(el)
   var w = ($el.parent().width() - $el.outerWidth())/2;
   var offset = $el.parent().scrollLeft();
   return w + offset;
}

var $slider = $('.slider-price');

console.log(xpos($slider));
console.log(ypos($slider));

var x = xpos($slider);
var y = ypos($slider);
$slider.data('position', {x:x, y:y});

// or
$slider.data('position', x + ', ' + y);
```

Comment: sure using a lot of extra `$()` calls than needed

Comment: Sweet! The values are correctly logged in the console, however the **<p>** remains the same. Here's what it's like: <p class="slider-price fs_obj fs_obj_active" data-in="fade" data-step="1" data-delay="250" data-out="fade" rel="0" data-fontsize="18px" style="opacity: 1; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; font-size: 18px; line-height: 100%;">
       $50,000
      </p>

Comment: @Radu don't confuse what you see in live html with setting `data('position', someVar)` it won't be visible in html

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, good to know! What I'm trying to say though it's that normally I should add the attribute 'data-position = "100, 100" ' by myself (I'm using FractionSlider, so this would position the element inside the slider). However I want the element to be centered, so I thought using jquery to get the center position would help.

Comment: @charlietfl - i cleaned things up a bit.  Mostly I was trying to show that if you break out the complicated stuff into helpers, it's easier to read and easier to see what's not working.  But you are right, that you can be much more efficient about calling $(...).  The edited code should be a little nicer.